# Work around when content too long for memo cell in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am building an Access database for purposes of uploading large bits of content to a website. We previously entered this into Excel, but are trying to streamline the process to help prevent errors. In several places, content runs over the maximum character limit for an excel cell and also the character limit in a memo field in Access (~65,000 characters). Previously we put as much content as we could into the original cell and created overflow cells. We instead want to pull all the content to a separate text file and include a reference to that text file in the cell where it belongs.

Is there a way to do this in VBA? I know I can flag when content will be too long, but can I somehow (1) have VBA create a new text file with a given file name; and (2) insert that file name into the cell?

Thanks for any thoughts or any other ideas on solving this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your final use case. The workaround could simply be to maintain a folder of `.txt` files and instead of storing the text data in the memo, store them in the file (by building some GUI, if the text is manually entered or with some simple code).

The file should be named using a GUID generator, and the GUID name should be stored in the database.

e.g.

```
fileName = "12b0f8f3-1142-48b8-96eb-914ba9e04f55.txt"
memoField.value = "12b0f8f3-1142-48b8-96eb-914ba9e04f55"
```